# How to redirect guest who are not logged in to HTTP 404 page instead of wordpress restrict error page while trying to access wp admin?

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I am designing my wordpress website and I want nobody should know that I am using wordpress for my site. I designed my custom login page with custom URL and managed my logged in users to get HTTP 404 error if they try to access wp-admin or wp-login but only thing left is that if a guest who is not logged in try to access wp admin by simply typing www.mydomain/wp-admin on browser gets wordpress error which reveals everything. So I need a code so those guests also get HTTP 404 error. They should be redirected 404 page only because I set a ban for those users who get more than 5 HTTP error. Anyone please help.

Comment: Very closely related: [What's the correct way to hide/prevent access to wp-admin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9210679)

Comment: You won't hide the fact you are using WP.  This redirect is the least of your worries.  There's many different ways to detect you are running WP.  **Note:** It *is* possible to have a login page within your theme, and to redirect not-logged-in users there, rather than to the wp-admin page.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I have done that all. The only thing I need to redirect non logged in users who try to access wp admin to 404 page instead of wordpress error page or elsewhere in  my site. They should be redirected 404 page only because I set a ban for those users who get more 5 HTTP error.